# Drop all data types in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to drop all the data types listed by `\dT+`.

I know you can drop types individually via `DROP TYPE` command, but I have a lot of types and it's painstaking to drop them all individually.

Comment: `psql -E` will show you the underlying SQL for psql commands. That will get you started.

Answer (score 2):

Following the directions suggested by user Schwern, I used `psql -E` and got this to work:

1. Run `SELECT typname, typnamespace from pg_type;`
2. Figure out what `typnamespace` your types are associated with
3. `DELETE FROM pg_type WHERE typnamespace=${your_typnamespace}`

Comment: This definitely worked, thanks!